# Error: Permission denied to access property "resizeTo"

Tags: javascript, dom-events, permission-denied

How to solve `Permission denied` error?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener(
        'message',
        function (event) {
            if (event.data.w && event.data.h) {
                pop.resizeTo(event.data.w, event.data.h); // Error: Permission denied to access property "resizeTo"
            }
        }
    );
   function popup(url) {
        pop = window.open(url, '', 'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=300,height=600');
        pop.resizeTo(50, 50); // no error here, resize works
    }
</script>
```

Note: `popup(url)` opens a popup on different domain.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the error isn't coming from the if statement when you check `if (event.data.h && event.data.w)`? I would imagine that if you don't have permission to access to the `event.data.h` or the `event.data.w` your error would manifest there.

Comment: No, the event data is coming

Comment: In the window.addEventListener what is pop defined as?

Comment: I know about JS variables, but if that line is executed before pop is defined you will be performing a resizeTo on an undefined variable. In that code, window.addEventListener will be the first fist line of JS to run when the page is loaded, meaning that pop will be undefined.

Comment: Apologies, I see my mistake in that statement. It will only be called when the even takes place. Just check that pop is defined before the event takes place.